# Is there a way to check if a random question has been flagged a duplicate of one of your questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Is there a feature that allows one to see whether a question, posted by some user, has been closed because it is considered a duplicate of a question that I had already posted?

Would it be a good idea to perhaps notify the original asker when a question has been flagged as a duplicate of one of their own questions? Or maybe keep track of how many questions were considered duplicates of an original one?

Comment: Probably not notify - not everyone cares to know that their question is spawning dupes, but it'd be nice to be able to find these duplicates. The Linked section in the sidebar considers duplicates, but of course, it also considers just about any other internal links (e.g. in comments, answers...) with no way of letting you see just dupes.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=duplicate  There's got to be a way for old posts, but I don't know how quite yet

Comment: @BoltClock While most of the time I wouldn't care; if someone else opened a dupe of one of mine that didn't have an accepted answer I'd like to know.  Both from the standpoint of being poked about if I eventually found a solution and forgot to answer it myself; and from the standpoint of if the new questioner might've noticed a detail about the problem I didn't that might lead me towards how to solve a still open issue.

Comment: I attempted to make a query with the Data Explorer yesterday but didn't get very far, this could probably be done via the Data Explorer though.

Comment: You may consider that these dup questions appear in the “Linked” section at the right of your question…

Comment: I think that it should be an important feature regarding determining duplicate. The user of the original post should be alerted about being a post is a duplicate of his/her post and his/her opinion should have heavier weight (value) in determining the state of duplicate.